# Windows Socket unable to bind on VPN IP address

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets, mfc

I am trying to bind to particular IP which is over a VPN network and I am able to ping it, connect it and also able to telnet on particular port but my windows MFC program gives error code 10049 and I am not able to go further any help in debugging this problem will be appreciated, I am running this on Visual Studio 2012 Win 7 and remote client is running on Linux variant.

This is part of code where I am getting error basically IP address is configurable but I am hardcoding it to debug.

```
   CStarDoc          *p_doc = (CStarDoc*) lpparam; 
   BOOL              fFlag = TRUE;
   const int         MAX_MSGLEN = max(sizeof(DISP_INFO_T ), sizeof(REASON_STRING_T ));
   char              buffer[MAX_MSGLEN];
   DISP_INFO_T       *p_disp_info_buffer = (DISP_INFO_T *) buffer;
   DISP_INFO_T       disp_info_combined; //receiving combined butter
   DISP_INFO_T_1     *p_disp_info_buffer1; //receiving buffer pointer for DispInfo1
   DISP_INFO_T_2     *p_disp_info_buffer2; //receiving buffer pointer for DispInfo2
   int               msgReceived = 0; // Initially, is 0. 
   // For the same msgNumber, when the program receives the first portion of buffer, set to 1,
   // When the program receives both portions, set it to 0. 
   // When the program misses any portion for the same msgNumber, set to 0 also.
   int               currentMsgNum1 = 0;  
   int               currentMsgNum2 = 0;  
   int               err;
   CString           msg;
   SOCKADDR_IN       saUDPPortIn;
   SOCKADDR_IN       From;

   struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
   struct addrinfo *ptr = NULL;
   struct addrinfo hints;
   ::memset( &hints,0, sizeof(hints) );
   hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
   //hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
   //hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
   char asideip[] = "192.168.1.129";
   BOOL              OtherSideIsStandby = FALSE; 
   static BOOL       DoFirstMsg = TRUE; 

   //   p_disp_info_combined = & disp_info_combined;
   p_doc->ThreadRunning = TRUE;
   p_doc->udpsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (INVALID_SOCKET == p_doc->udpsocket)
   {
       CString msg =  "Invalid socket: "+ WSAGetLastError();
       AfxMessageBox(msg);
       return(-1);
   }

   long ip = 0;
   int sockbufsize = 0; 
   int timeout = 2000; 

   // This is the IP that matches the IP of the QNX machines in all but the last octet. 
   // Note: it is in host byte format. 
   int errcode = getaddrinfo(asideip,NULL,&hints,&result);
   for(ptr = result;ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) 
   {
       switch (ptr->ai_family) 
       {
         default: break;
         case AF_INET :
           ip = p_doc->MyIP;
           saUDPPortIn.sin_family = AF_INET;
           saUDPPortIn.sin_addr.s_addr = (((SOCKADDR_IN*) ptr->ai_addr)->sin_addr).s_addr;
           saUDPPortIn.sin_port = htons(p_doc->port_addr );
           int length = sizeof(buffer) *2;
           //err = setsockopt(p_doc->udpsocket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&fFlag, sizeof(fFlag));
           //err = setsockopt(p_doc->udpsocket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&fFlag, sizeof(fFlag));
           err = setsockopt(p_doc->udpsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&length, sizeof(length));

           // Keep from hanging forever. 
           err = setsockopt(p_doc->udpsocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
           err = bind(p_doc->udpsocket, (SOCKADDR FAR *)&saUDPPortIn, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
           if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
           {
             int errcode = WSAGetLastError();
             closesocket(p_doc->udpsocket); 
             /*    msg.Format("Network Connectivity failed, Please Check Network. "); 
             AfxMessageBox(msg);   
             closesocket(p_doc->udpsocket); 
         p_doc->udpsocket = -1;                                          // task is trying to attach to the port.   
             return(1);*/
           }
       }
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not bind to remote address and as your error shows, it is such case. You use bind system call with local IP and Port.

Here is what MSDN says about your error:

> WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL 10049
>
> Cannot assign requested address. The requested address is not valid in
>   its context. This normally results from an attempt to bind to an
>   address that is not valid for the local computer. This can also result
>   from connect, sendto, WSAConnect, WSAJoinLeaf, or WSASendTo when the
>   remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for
>   example, address or port 0).

Comment: But the socket is UDP socket and I am binding it so that I don't have to use sendto call.

Comment: It does not matter what type of socket you use. bind call basically makes your process to listen for connection at a socket (IP + Port).